# how it works with mongoose multiple update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Array;

```
 arr=[
  {
  id: [ '5e6e9b0668fcbc7bce2097ac', '5e6e9b0e68fcbc7bce2097af' ],
  color: [ 'a', 'b' ]
  }
 ]
```

Models;

```
const varyant = Models.varyant
```

function;

```
Promise.all(

 arr.map((item)=>{ 

 return varyant.updateMany({"_id": item.id }, {"$set":   { "color":"value" }  }, 

 {multi:true}); 

 })).then(function(results){

 });
```

this function success,  write color:"value"

but change

```
 return varyant.updateMany({"_id": item.id }, {"$set":{ "color":{ $in: arr.color } }  },
```

nodejs output:

```
 (node:62738) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ '$in': [ 'a', 'b' ] }" at path "color"
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) is not a insert operator is a select operator

Comment: The result does not change when I change it like {"$set":   { "color":arr.color } (node:62943) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[ 'a', 'b' ]" at path "color"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $in is not a insert operator is a select operator

You could change the `arr` array with some easy suitable format

```js
const arr = [{
  id: ['5e6e9b0668fcbc7bce2097ac', '5e6e9b0e68fcbc7bce2097af'],
  color: ['a', 'b']
}];

const new_arr = arr[0].id.map((id,i)=>({id,color:arr[0].color[i]}));

//[{id,color}]

Promise.all(
  new_arr.map((item, i) => {
    return varyant.updateMany({
      "_id": item.id
    }, {
      "$set": {
        "color": item.color,
      }
    }, {
      multi: true
    });

  })).then(function(results) {

});
```